# AJAX POST function is returning an error before it even goes through POST method in controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an AJAX function that looks like this

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@IGT.baseUrl/JODetails/SpecialOrderSelection",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ allParts: array }),
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function () {
       alert('Success!');
    },
     error: function () {
       alert('Error! ');
    }
    });
```

The array isn't being sent to my method that looks like this

```
public ActionResult SpecialOrderSelection(ItemViewModel model, ItemPartViewModel[] allParts)
{
       
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        JobOrder jobOrder = db.JobOrders.Find(model.Id);
        if (jobOrder == null)
           {
              return HttpNotFound();
           }
        ViewBag.JobOrderID = jobOrder.ID;
        TempData["model"] = model;
        return RedirectToAction("SpecialOrderSummary", new { id = model.Id });
     }
            
     return View(model);
            
}
```

Here is my itemViewModel

```
 public class ItemViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string MFGNumber { get; set; }
        public IList<ItemPartViewModel> Parts { get; set; }      
    }
```

And here is my ItemPartView model

```
 public class ItemPartViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public string PartID { get; set; }
        public string MFGNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartName { get; set; }
        public float QtyInItem { get; set; }
        public float Qty { get; set; }
        public bool MoveAll { get; set; }
        public float OnHand { get; set; }
        public float OnWorkOrder { get; set; }
        public float Committed { get; set; }
        public float FSTK { get; set; }

        // This is the additional property to contain what user picks
        public PartActionType SelectedActionType { get; set; }
    }
```

allParts is returning as NULL (I confirmed the array as data in it from the console log) and the view page is responding with the "ERROR!" message before the code even runs through the POST method.

Why is this?

Comment: "@IGT.baseUrl" is this some class-helper for view? Maybe you can't call C# classed in ajax?

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab in your browsers DevTools to see to what URL your request is being made? If it's a CORS request, most browsers execute an OPTION request on POST in order to validate that the URL allows for CORS. This will cause an error immediately and not call your method

Comment: @witheroux it goes to the method, there is just a popup of the alert 'error' message

Comment: Did you also post `model` data? And do you have data validations on your `ItemViewModel`? What is the value of `ModelState.IsValid`?

Comment: The problem was it was doing an automatic post. So I added in event.prevent default and also I am passing the view model through my ajax now @jasen

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `JSON.stringify()` method ?

Use ajax just by sending original json object.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@IGT.baseUrl/JODetails/SpecialOrderSelection",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { allParts: array },
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function () {
       alert('Success!');
    },
    error: function () {
       alert('Error! ');
    }
});
```

Comment: Because allParts keeps returning null

Comment: Post your `ItemViewModel` and `ItemPartViewModel` class and json of `array`. It will help us to analyse your question.